# How can I autofill a formula in Numbers, but keep some referenced values the same?

Tags: macos, ios, numbers, iwork

So I have a chart in Numbers (iOS version, but I can use the macOS version, if needed,) which has formula that references some values from the chart, as well as some values from a different chart. I want to autofill this formula, while keeping the references from the other chart the same.

I want A2 to change for each row, A3, A4, etc. But I want values from table 2 to stay referenced to B2.

> [image: Numbers]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the up arrow to the right of the cell reference (at the bottom of your screenshot) for the one you want to fix, then check the Row and Column boxes to fix the reference to both the row and column.